# Removing a string from array MongoDB object

Tags: mongodb

I have objects like in my collection:

```
{
   "foo": {
       "actions": [
          ...,
          "delete"
       ]
   },
   "bar": {
      "tags": ["links", ...]
   }
}
```

I want to remove `delete` value from `foo.actions` from all objects that contain `links` value in `bar.tags` field.

I tried to do a basic update that seems not to work:

```
db.foo.update({
   "bar.tags": /links/
}, {
   $pull: {
       "foo.actions": "delete"
   }
}, {
   multi: true
});
```

`delete` field is not removed since the following request doesn't return `0`:

```
> db.foo.find({"bar.tags": /links/, "foo.actions": /delete/}).count()
786
```

What's the issue here? Why `delete` value is not removed?

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK `tags` is inside of another object. Maybe that makes the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked for me. Maybe you're not calling the right collection.
What you want to do is print the count before and after the update to see if there's a difference.

Example:

```
db.foo.find({"bar.tags": /links/, "foo.actions": /delete/}).count() // 4
db.foo.update({
   "bar.tags": /links/
}, {
   $pull: {
       "foo.actions": "delete"
   }
}, {
   multi: true
});
db.foo.find({"bar.tags": /links/, "foo.actions": /delete/}).count() // 0
```

Setup

```
var createObj = function(){
  var o = {
     "foo": {
         "actions": [
            "ok"
         ]
     },
     "bar": {
        "tags": ["links"]
     }
  }
  if( Math.random() < 0.5 ){
    o.foo.actions.push("delete");
    o.foo.actions.push("delete");
    o.foo.actions.push("delete");
  }
  return o;
};
use test;
db.foo.drop();
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  db.foo.insert( createObj() );
}
```

Comment: It's strange that running `db.foo.update({"bar.tags": "links", "foo.actions": "delete"}, {"$pull": {"foo.actions": "delete"}}, {multi: true})` worker perfectly. Anyway, thanks for great answer!

Comment: The issue appeared because I was having a field `deleteImage` in `foo.actions`. When I was counting `foo.actions: /delete/` they were being caught. Can you please update your answer with this information? May be useful for future users.

Comment: You might want to use a string instead of a regular expression next time. Because `/delete/` matches any word that contains `delete` and not just the word `delete`. `/^delete$/` is the same as `"delete"`.